# Should I use Welch's (1947) approximate degrees of freedom or Satterthwaite's (1946)?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, degrees-of-freedom

I'm confused as to the correct formula for approximate degrees of freedom to use for Welch's t-test. Satterthwaite's (1946) formula is the most commonly cited formula, but Welch gave an alternative in 1947. I'm not sure which is preferable (or used by most statistical software).

Satterthwaite's formula:
$$\frac{\left(s_x^2/n_x +s_y^2/n_y\right)^2}{(s_x^2/n_x )^2/(n_x-1)+(s_y^2/n_y )^2/(n_y-1)}$$

Welch's formula:
$$-2+ \frac{\left(s_x^2/n_x +s_y^2/n_y\right)^2}{(s_x^2/n_x )^2/(n_x+1)+(s_y^2/n_y )^2/(n_y+1)}$$

References:

- Satterthwaite, F.E. (1946). "An Approximate Distribution of Estimates of Variance Components". *Biometrics Bulletin*, 2, 6, pp. 110–114.
- Welch, B.L. (1947). "The generalization of "Student's" problem when several different population variances are involved". *Biometrika*, 34, 1/2, pp. 28–35.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to CV!

I cannot answer on which one is preferred (they are actually really close so I don't think it matters much), but generally, major statistical software packages use Satterthwaite's method. `SPSS` and `SAS` both use it. In `Stata`, some commands like `ttest` would allow user to specify Welch's method, but Satterthwaite's is still the default.

And in literature, I have mostly seen Satterthwaite's formula being cited. Time to time it's referred to as Satterthwaite-Welch's degrees of freedom, but the formula cited is Satterthwaite's. I guess having published it one year earlier did matter.

Comment: For what it's worth to the OP, I don't think I've ever actually seen the version of the formula attributed to Welch, so I would agree with Penguin_Knight that Satterthwaite's is in more common use.

Comment: Welch originally published in 1938, not 1946: Welch, B. L. (1938) "The significance of the difference between two means when the population variances are unequal", Biometrika 29, 350–62.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments. I actually found the answer - in Aspin's 1949 paper Welch adds a comment in the appendix refuting his degrees of freedom formula. So looks like Satterthwaite's is the one to use! Aspin, A. A. (1949). Biometrika, 36, 290–296.