# Unequal Variances: Satterthwaite vs Welch

Tags: t-test

I'm currently working on a statistics analysis that has a small study population, n=50. I've segmented the population into two groups and want to perform some t-tests to compare differences between some of the measures we used during data collection.

I know I need to assume unequal variances and Stata gives me two options, Satterthwaite and Welch. My question is, which is more appropriate to use in this situation?

Comment: This was asked before: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70959/should-i-use-welchs-1947-approximate-degrees-of-freedom-or-satterthwaites-1